# Relation between ORPort and ServerTransportListenAddr

Tags: configuration, pluggable-transports, obfsproxy

I am working on setting up a Tor `obfs4` bridge. If I understand it correctly `ServerTransportListenAddr` allows me to choose a port (and an IP) to bind the Pluggable Transport to. However I also need to set an `ORPort` and Tor logs that it does reachability tests.

Doesn't this defeat the whole point of using a pluggable transport and obfs4 in particular? Couldn't an attacker just look for the normal ORPort and thereby detect the bridge as such?

Do I need to forward the ORPort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attacker wouldn't be able to find you if nobody tries to connect to your ORPort. If you didn't publish the bridge descriptor, nobody will know your ORPort.

Comment: But then there are a few open questions: Why not randomize it and why does it have to be open then (having reachability tests)?

Comment: It can be random (just input random number) and even unreachable. Even if reachability test fails, your bridge will still run well.

Comment: Okay, thank you. And it will still be propagated to bridge authorities?

Comment: It looks like [there is a ticket for this](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6396)